# 非constexprセンテンス中のconstexprを定数化する方法

Tags: c++, c++11

`constexpr`を非`constexpr`センテンス中で使用すると定数になりませんが、簡単な回避方法はないでしょうか。

使用環境: gcc-4.9.2 (MSYS2 32bit), 最適化なし

テストコードを示します。逆アセンブル時の読みやすさのため`iostream`ではなく`printf()`を使っています。

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <int N> struct Fact    { static const int _ = N * Fact<N - 1>::_; };
template <>      struct Fact<1> { static const int _ = 1; };

constexpr int fact(int n) {
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1);
}

int main() {
    printf("fact 10 = %d\n", Fact<10>::_);
    printf("fact 10 = %d\n", fact(10));
}
```

`main()`を逆アセンブルした該当箇所を引用します。

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -g fact.cpp
$ objdump -S -Mintel a.exe
...snip...
  printf("fact 10 = %d\n", Fact<10>::_);
4011ce:       c7 44 24 04 00 5f 37    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x375f00
4011d5:       00
4011d6:       c7 04 24 64 30 40 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x403064
4011dd:       e8 46 00 00 00          call   401228 <_printf>
  printf("fact 10 = %d\n", fact(10));
4011e2:       c7 04 24 0a 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0xa
4011e9:       e8 b2 05 00 00          call   4017a0 <__Z4facti>
4011ee:       89 44 24 04             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
4011f2:       c7 04 24 64 30 40 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x403064
4011f9:       e8 2a 00 00 00          call   401228 <_printf>
...snip...
```

テンプレートの方はコンパイル時評価で定数化されていますが、constexprは実行時評価です。

一時変数に入れるとコンパイル時評価されますが、同じ定数が二か所で現れてしまいます。（最適化なし）

```
#include <stdio.h>

constexpr int fact(int n) {
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1);
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto n = fact(10);
    printf("fact 10 = %d\n", n);
}
```

逆アセンブル:（該当箇所のみ）

```
  constexpr auto n = fact(10);
4011ce:       c7 44 24 1c 00 5f 37    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x375f00
4011d5:       00
  printf("fact 10 = %d\n", n);
4011d6:       c7 44 24 04 00 5f 37    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x375f00
4011dd:       00
4011de:       c7 04 24 64 30 40 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x403064
4011e5:       e8 2a 00 00 00          call   401214 <_printf>
```

テンプレートで細工すればコンパイル時に評価されます。

```
#include <stdio.h>

constexpr int fact(int n) {
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1);
}

template <typename T, T N> struct C { static const T _ = N; };

int main() {
    printf("fact 10 = %d\n", C<int, fact(10)>::_);
}
```

逆アセンブル:（該当箇所のみ）

```
  printf("fact 10 = %d\n", C<int, fact(10)>::_);
4011ce:       c7 44 24 04 00 5f 37    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x375f00
4011d5:       00
4011d6:       c7 04 24 64 30 40 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x403064
4011dd:       e8 2a 00 00 00          call   40120c <_printf>
```

これは結局テンプレートの力を借りているので釈然としません。

質問をまとめます。

- 前提条件: 最適化なし
- テンプレートを使わずに、`constexpr`だけで式中の呼び出しをコンパイル時に評価できないでしょうか。
- もし無理なら、上の例で独自に定義した`C`のような標準関数はないでしょうか。

### 追記

テンプレートメタプログラミングを`constexpr`に置き換える際、前者の感覚で使うとコンパイル時評価にならない落とし穴として、何か定石があるのではないかと期待した質問です。

Comment: `printf` が `constexpr` な関数ではないからという話ではないでしょうか？

Comment: それは了解していますが、そのような場合に定数化する定石があれば知りたいのです。

Comment: 僕は定石はわからないのですが、「上の例で独自に定義したCのような標準関数はないでしょうか。」を訪ねる質問にしたほうがいいのではないでしょうか？「テンプレートを使わずに、constexprだけで式中の呼び出しをコンパイル時に評価できないでしょうか。」は呼び出し側の関数が constexpr かどうかで変わるため常にコンパイル時に評価できるわけではないことが明確なため必要ないのでは？と思います。

Comment: 疑似コードですが`printf("fact 10 = %d\n", constexpr fact(10));`のような回避策が、仕様上あるのかもしれないということを期待しています。その手の抜け道が自力では見付けられなかったため質問しました。

Comment: 最適化なしでも定数化したいというのは少々特殊な要求だとおもったのですが、何か理由があるのでしょうか？コンパイル時の最適化（定数伝搬）が効くケースでは、constexpr無しでもコンパイル時に計算されるケースもありますし。

Comment: テンプレートで書いていたものを機械的にconstexprに置き替えたら実行時間がやけに違ったので、なぜかと調べたのが発端です。初歩的なミスかと思いましたが、類似事例を見付けられなかったため、質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

テンプレートを使わないという条件であれば、配列と sizeof を使ったインチキが使えます。
ただし size_t に収まる型に限られる上に、テンプレートを使う方法の劣化版なので無意味です。

```
#include <cstdio>

constexpr int fact(int n) {
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1);
}

int main() {
    std::printf("fact 10 = %d\n", (int)sizeof(char[fact(10)]));
}
```

テンプレートを使うのであれば、マクロにすることで型の指定を省略することができます。

```
#define AS_CONSTANT(expr) (std::integral_constant<decltype(expr), (expr)>::value)
```

いずれにせよ、通常の式中の一部分を定数式評価に強制する方法は、現在の標準では存在しないと思われます。

Comment: 本家SOで同話題を集約した質問"[single expression helper for compile-time enforced constexpr function evaluation possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309245/)"がありました。同じ手法をとっているようです。